# Log4j prints json key name when value is null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, log4j

I am having a problem with printing my context variables by log4j.
If variable is null then it's printed like:
{ "status":"${ctx:status}" }

But I want it to be printed like:
{ "status":"" }

Please share your ideas with me.

Comment: can you show the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wanted to add some details for `s7vr's` answer. I totally agree with answer, but there is work around. The issue with printing empty value is depended on `jackson-databind` library. If you use value pattern as below

```
<KeyValuePair key="status" value="$${ctx:status:-}"/>
```

and want to put empty string in final json object, you can use the version of `jackson-databind` no newer than `2.10.5`.

This means the following configuration will work:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.14.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are better off providing **non empty** default value for cases where the variable look up returns null or missing. The current implementation returns the value as is when it can not be resolved. Adding a default value would return the default value when it can't be resolved.

```
<KeyValuePair key="status" value="$${ctx:status:-missingornullorempty}"/>
```

Adding an empty default value will remove the field from log message as the log4j json object mappper is configured to only include non empty field (https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/master/log4j-layout-jackson-json/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/jackson/json/Log4jJsonObjectMapper.java#L48) and currently there is no way to configure the object mapper (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-2670).

Answer (score 1):

without dispalying your current implementation it is rather hard to know what has already been attempted. The following code is a method that logs a variable.

```
    private static DataNotFoundException notFound(final long id) {
        log.warn("Event not found for id: {}", id);
        return new DataNotFoundException("No group event found with id " + id);
    }
```

If the following is what returns a null, then we can use the NullAppender class of Log4j2. I advise looking at the [Apache documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/extending.html#Appenders) for the boilerplate code necessary to implement the following:

```
@Plugin(name = "Stub", category = "Core", elementType = "appender", printObject = true)
public final class StubAppender extends AbstractOutputStreamAppender<StubManager> {
 
    private StubAppender(String name,
                         Layout<? extends Serializable> layout,
                         Filter filter,
                         boolean ignoreExceptions,
                         StubManager  manager) {
        super(name, layout, filter, ignoreExceptions, true, manager);
    }
 
    @PluginFactory
    public static StubAppender createAppender(@PluginAttribute("name") String name,
                                              @PluginAttribute("ignoreExceptions") boolean ignoreExceptions,
                                              @PluginElement("Layout") Layout layout,
                                              @PluginElement("Filters") Filter filter) {
 
        if (name == null) {
            LOGGER.error("No name provided for StubAppender");
            return null;
        }
 
        StubManager manager = StubManager.getStubManager(name);
        if (manager == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (layout == null) {
            layout = PatternLayout.createDefaultLayout();
        }
        return new StubAppender(name, layout, filter, ignoreExceptions, manager);
    }
}
```